# Row comparison and append loop by columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a bunch of school data that I maintain on a master list for monthly testing scores. Everytime a child takes a score and there is an update on 'Age', 'Score', 'School' I would insert a new row with updated data and keep track of all the changes. I am trying to figure out a python script to do this but since I am a newbie, I keep running in to issues.

I tried writing a loop but keep getting errors to include "False", "The Truth value of a series is ambigious", "tuple indices must be integers, not str"

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
             'Age':[15,14,17,13],
             'School':['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH'],
             'Score':[80, 75, 62, 100],
             'Date': ['3/1/2019', '3/1/2019', '3/1/2019', '3/1/2019']})

updates_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
             'Age':[16,14,17,13],
             'School':['AB', 'ZX', 'EF', 'GH'],
             'Score':[80, 90, 62, 100],
             'Date': ['4/1/2019', '4/1/2019', '4/1/2019', '4/1/2019']})

# What I am trying to get is:  

updated_master = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','D'],
             'Age':[15,16,14,14,17,13],
             'School':['AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'ZX', 'EF', 'GH'],
             'Score':[80, 80, 75, 90, 62, 100],
             'Date': ['3/1/2019', '4/1/2019', '3/1/2019', '4/1/2019', '3/1/2019', '3/1/2019']})

temp_delta_list = []
m_score = master_df.iloc[1:, master_df.columns.get_loc('Score')]
m_age = master_df.iloc[1:, master_df.columns.get_loc('Age')]
m_school = master_df.iloc[1:, master_df.columns.get_loc('School')]

u_score = updates_df.iloc[1:, updates_df.columns.get_loc('Score')]
u_age = updates_df.iloc[1:, updates_df.columns.get_loc('Age')]
u_school = updates_df.iloc[1:, updates_df.columns.get_loc('School')]



for i in updates_df['ID'].values:
    updated_temp_score = updates_df[updates_df['ID'] == i], u_score
    updated_temp_age = updates_df[updates_df['ID'] == i], u_age
    updated_temp_school = updates_df[updates_df['ID'] == i], u_school


    master_temp_score = master_df[master_df['ID'] == i], m_score
    master_temp_age = master_df[master_df['ID'] == i], m_age
    master_temp_school = updates_df[master_df['ID'] == i], m_school

if (updated_temp_score == master_temp_score) | (updated_temp_age == master_temp_age) | (updated_temp_school == master_temp_school):
   pass
else:
   temp_deltas = updates_df[(updates_df['ID'] == i)]
   temp_delta_list.append(temp_deltas)
```

I ultimately want to have the loop compare each row values for each ID and return rows that have any difference and then append the master_df

Comment: To clarify your logic, why is student 'D' not in the updated_master twice, since they have an updated 'School' entry? Is it _any_ or _all_ of age/score/school that needs to change to be included?

Comment: Just to note: There doesn't seem to be any reason to loop through your df. Look into pd.concat() and pd.drop_duplicates() for efficient, vectorized operations

Comment: @ G. Anderson thanks for the finding the errors, I edited. Basically I need to capture if any thing changes. I don't know if drop_duplicates might delete anything that changed. If I drop on ID then I might lose all additional rows. We are trying to track the kids as they get older or move to another school within the district

Comment: Given this, I'm confused by your output. In your `updated_master` df, you show only one entry for student `D`, even though there are entries for two different schools in the original `master_df` and the `updates_df`, shouldn;t there be an entry for each of `['GH','PS']` in your output?

Comment: For an example, try running this code and see if that gets close to your ideal outcome `pd.concat([master_df,updates_df]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Age','Score','School']).sort_index()`

Comment: @ G. Anderson thanks for the help I figured it out. This is solved by looping a set compare which will build a temp dataframe and then append the original. Thank you for the help anyways